# Enrich a serialized proto message without affect the existing property?

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

I have a chain of 3 services (A => B => C) and a simple proto message (M).
The message:

```proto
message M {
   string name = 2;
   int32 id = 2; // new key
}
```

A and C hold the latest version of M (above) while B holds an old version (without the `id` key).
B receives an instance of M, enriches it with `name` value, and passes it to C.

Is there a way to preserve the values of the 'id' while B modifies this message, so C will have both 'id' value and the enrichments?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to update the definition for B as well and recompile (so your class/struct in your language of choice will have the id prop too), and then just modify the name prop and leave the id untouched.

Comment: What library/tooling versions are you using? Historically proto2 would preserve unknown fields; your messages look like proto3, and early proto3 versions *did not* preserve unknown fields, but: from 3.5 onwards, this should now just work out of the box. So: what library/tooling version are you using, and does "update everything to at lest 3.5" suffice? https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#unknowns